# Entity Framework Code First with MVC : Adding filtering functionality (OrderBy) disrupts ViewBag context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sorting, model-view-controller, viewbag

When I have just simple Index() action code:

[image]

It works fine. All columns(especially HiredDate, FiredDate) display properly, like in this image below:
[image]

**But as soon as I add filtering/sorting code:**

[image]

It breaks the ViewBag, and doesn't show proper HiredDate and FiredDate like on this image below, however sorting works:

[image]

This is how I call HiredDate and FiredDate(in both scenarios) inside Index.cshtml to view the data:
[image]

Finally this is how GetDates() function is initialized:

```
public List<EmployeeDate> GetDates()
        {
            List<EmployeeDate> results;
            using (CompanyContext context = new CompanyContext())
            {
                results = _context.EmployeeDates.Include(x => x.Employee).ToList();
                return results;
            }
        }
```

So how can I group this sorting code together with my ViewBag, so that Sorting works and Table displays all data properly?

DB ERD:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you have the dates in another table.
Why don't you use join to relate the two tables and thus make a single query?

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators

```
_dbContext.Employee.Join(
_dbContext.EmployeeDate,
        empl => Employee.id,
        data => EmployeeDate.idEmployee,
        (empl , data ) => new
        {
            id= empl.Id,
            name= empl.name,
            date= data.date1
        }
    ).ToList();
```

if you use table relations (Foreign key)

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

await DbContext.dbset.where(x => x.yourColoumn == yourValue).Include (x => x.yourNavigationId).ToListAsync ();
```

I advise using asynchronous methods because if the application will have a large audience, it will use fewer resources and it will be more performant and reduce number of threads and memory.

Comment: I used AsNoTracking() from this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Yes I have Dates in Child Table. To be exact I have Employee (Parent) and EmployeeDate (as child).
How do you make a single query?

Comment: I mean how do you join them

Comment: `var emps = from s in _context.Employees.Include(x => x.EmployeeDates).ToList() select s;`

if I do this, it underlines AsNoTracking and says - CS1061 C# does not contain a definition for and no accessible extension method accepting a first argument of type could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)